# How can I define a metric with (+,-,-,-) signature in xTensor

Tags: physics, xact

Can I define the metric with (+,-,-,-) sign by using the DefMetric[1,metric[-a,-b], CD]? Does "1" in the first place refer to the sign of the time component of the metric or the determinent. If it refers to the determinent then we can use -1 for both (-,+,+,+) and (+,-,-,-) signature. Then my question is where the signature of the metric plays a role, for example if we calculate the energy momentum tensor for a given action then the definition of energy momentum tensor depends on the signature of our metric.

Please help me out, thanks .

Comment: Try ask in this forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/xAct